# ASP.NET bundling - saving generated bundles to disk

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, save, bundling-and-minification, asp.net-bundling

I have a lot of bundles. For offline purposes I need to save them to disk. I currently use `WebClient.DownloadFile` for this, but I have to mantain a separate list of bundles to call `DownloadFile` on.

Can you please advise me on a better method for this. I think it could work with Transformers or some fictional BundleTable.ListAllBundles() + bundle.GetMinifiedVersion() approach, but I did not find any working examples that would give me the minified version of the script in a string or allow saving to disk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up iterating over the bundles and adding them to the list of files to download

```
foreach (var b in BundleTable.Bundles) {
    pagesToDownload.Add(b.Path);
}
```